# How to decrypt a file using RSA and just a public.pem file?

Tags: rsa, openssl, decryption

I have an encoded file and a public.pem file. Is it possible to decode the file using the public.pem file or do I have to start looking at private keys?

I tried https://github.com/Ganapati/RsaCtfTool with no luck. The public key (pem) is as below

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAjHDiqVkO1umD2/Tm20Wt
LpyBXGoIk4Pczeqjwz7/kwYLnQI7VlAzgjC9jD1dX80Z+kLOr5wHIDdfNK55nC/q
ux/g7xVt0YKMl5yzObHUgX0YUi//8k2a5YfidxWoX77B7GfuBKx0efEsM7p+7cYT
z7OVKFdRIvKATMGsYlWOPT9b97OtTQjtZKyhAtL1PdbfqKCCxRzqvj1OthtHbB+b
4AJG4MI2IHJQ0LHyj83md3iIMQSMZxwe8JsWQs3jW7W1xRDWjDsKn1799kPTTgG3
GtVrO6J38HN5t5dk8ZNa7duh9phRyEBQbo2lH/tYqUBKeJ3v/dA0BhQVMdZe5m8R
uQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Comment: What is the origin of this Q?

Answer (score 3):

Adding on to the above, the modulus and public exponent can be extracted
from the public.pem.  The public exponent e is 10001.

It turns out that this is a constructed modulus which is very weak and
was not generated using recommended security guidelines.

The 2048 bit, 617 decimal digit modulus N=pq can be factored immediately
because it is a square. That's right p=q and N = p^2.

phi(N) = p(p-1)

The method to find d the private exponent when e, p and q are known has been
shown many times on this forum.  Then the file can be decrypted.

Comment: Good catch on the square, but phi(p^2) is NOT (p-1)x(p-1). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Value_of_phi_for_a_prime_power_argument .

Comment: Corrected. Thanks.  The error could have led someone down a time consuming path.

Comment: Any advice on a good question/answer that would highlight how to find the numbers @MostlyResults

Comment: If your ctf question insists that a file or text can be decrypted from 
the public.pem even though p and q are the same, look at the answer 
to the second question in this link: 
https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/52240/why-does-this-rsa-example-break-when-1-setting-p-or-q-as-non-prime-or-2-sett

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to decode the file using the public.pem file

No.

> or do I have to start looking at private keys?

Yes.

[RSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)) is an [asymmetric encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) algorithm.  That means that its keys come in pairs, containing a public key and a private key, and that data encrypted with the public key can only be decrypted with the private key.

Comment: [Dr. Spock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spock) would qualify _"data encrypted with the public key can only be decrypted with the private key"_ as technically incorrect. Poorly thought RSA padding (as common in CTFs and introductions to RSA, including textbook RSA) may allow decryption without private key. So can access to a decryption device in Bleichenbacher's attack on RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5. And in all RSA encryption modes of PKCS#1, any of multiple private keys allow decryption.

Comment: Thanks - it as indeed for a CTF and was possible